# Get destination of save in DocumentBeforeSave

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a template in which I want to display the document path in the footer just before a save happends.

I have got the DocumentBeforeSave Sub all ready and functioning but the problem is I seem to have no way to get the destination path for the document, unless i'm missing something.

```
Private WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' UPDATE FOOTER HERE '
End Sub
```

I first thought that maybe the parameter Doc contained the destination, but I've only found the current directory.

The problem is only when doing a 'Save As', otherwise the footer don't need changing.

Comment: If you think this twice, you'll probably figure out that if document is not saved, it cannot have a file path, it simply doesn't exist. What you need to do is save the document, fetch the path, insert it to the footer, and save again..

Comment: The problem with that is, how do I know when a Save has occured? There is no DocumentAfterSave event.
Is there someway to hook into the save event and do the update there?

Comment: How about using `DocumentBeforeClose`, is that an option?

Answer (score 0):

By now you know you need to save as a '.docm' if you have VBA code. Not that the following will do what you want, but it is an example of how to see the default save path, and the 'latest' save path for this document. I set it to display different messages (on close) if someone does a SaveAs.

```
Option Explicit
Dim strPath     As String

Private Sub Document_Open()
    MsgBox "On Open, default save path is: " & Options.DefaultFilePath(wdDocumentsPath)
    strPath = ActiveDocument.Path
End Sub
Private Sub Document_Close()
    If strPath <> ActiveDocument.Path Then
        MsgBox "Document now in DIFFERENT path." & vbCrLf & _
                "On Close, document was saved at: " & ActiveDocument.Path & vbCrLf & _
                "Originally the document was in path: " & strPath
    Else
        MsgBox "Document still in same path." & vbCrLf & _
                "On Close, document was saved at: " & ActiveDocument.Path & vbCrLf & _
                "Full Path & Name: " & ActiveDocument.FullName
    End If
End Sub
```